# Culling/Managing Azure Log Files / Failed Request Logs in Blob Storage

Tags: iis, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I've just discovered that I have 100's of GB of log files/failed request logs on Azure Blob storage that have been accumulating over the years. Is there a tool or technique for managing them - the directory structure is convoluted so its not as easy as just sorting by date (I use Cloud Storage Studio as an Azure management tool)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[With apologies in advance if it feels like product plug] You could possibly look into Azure Diagnostics Manager (http://www.cerebrata.com/Products/AzureDiagnosticsManager). This tool is built specifically for viewing/managing Windows Azure Diagnostics. You could also look into Azure Management Studio (http://www.cerebrata.com) which combines Cloud Storage Studio and Azure Diagnostics Manager into one product and is currently in public beta.

Both tools allow you to purge old data, search for logs data based on date ranges.

(Disclosure: I'm part of Cerebrata team)

Comment: I did ask for *tool* or technique so product plugs are fine :-)